# how do I burn more than one movie onto a DVD

Tags: dvd, burning

I burned one movie on a dvd with 1.65gb on a DVD with 8.5 gb.  Now when I try to burn another movie on it tells me there is no disk space.   Can anyone tell me how to overcome this or what is going on.   When I check the contects of space lefton the DVD it says it is full??  How can this be.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you *finalized* the disc after burning the first file. That's the default setting on some burning software.
If that's the case, then there's no way to undo/reopen it, even if the disc was rewritable. Your best option is to check your settings before you try with another disc.

Here's an information page on Microsoft's website for reference:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Close-or-finalize-a-CD-or-DVD

Comment: Might I ask which burning software you used?

Answer (score 0):

More than one movie onto a single dvd is complicated for other reasons as well.  Indexing, chapter file numbering, etc.  I would try getting all video as a single file and resplitting chapters after that.  Different approach(still disc at once and finalize), but it fixes the chapter numbering.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of trying to burn multiple small ISO files to one disk. I downloaded one program in four separate segments as it was available, and made an ISO file of each. When it came to burning as one, it seemed it couldn't easily be done.

However I used Imgburn a great program. After I selected "write image file to disk" I found in the select a file panel there is an option to create a cue. Add files one at a time in order to the cue, then burn.

It created a DVD that plays through as one or skip between sections as chapters. Works great.